# Redirect uri mismatch after deploying on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have a link to my app hosted on Azure Web app which redirects to Azure B2C custom registration page. I have added the hosted domain to redirect urls even with ending / slashes into Application's Redirect URIs. But still gets the mismatch error. Any idea why is it happening?

link is like:
https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/some_url_defined_in_rest_api?attrs=some_data

This will hit the API and after checking some_date for validation it will redirect to the b2c registration page

Also in Azure Web App I have configured a virtual pat the REST API as:
[image]

Do I need to add that virtual path too?
https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/some.virtual.path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual path is not required to be included in the Redirect URIs unless it is specifically part of the URL that should be passed on to Azure B2C.

If the redirect URL in an Azure Web App includes a specific path like `/example_url_in_rest_api`, you must include that same URL in the Application's Redirect URIs in your Azure B2C application registration. Check for any query parameters are present and add those if they are part of the URL.

Remove the redirect URI from your application and re-add it.  Sometimes, it may help in resolving the issue.

*Check the B2C tenant applications by going to Azure resource Graph query as shown below:*

*Path:* `Azure AD B2C >> Open a query >> Run the B2C list` of queries.

[image]

If still the issue persists, you can try monitoring the `HTTP traffic` between your application and Azure AD B2C with a tool like [Fiddler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/fiddler-web-debugger-tool) (for debugging web applications).  This could help you to identify any issues with the redirect URI or other configuration settings.

Comment: what if I have a link on an email and that link directly goes to our api and from api it redirects to the Azure? this mechanism worked in local but not working when hosted on azure

Comment: Check that the API endpoint is properly configured and equivalent. If still the issue persists, use managed identities to access the resources and check whether there are any more redirect URL blockers like network restrictions on the platform you used. @JuliyanageSilva